# The index 1 is out of range error in java application

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When I run this code:

```
String s = "insert into PersonalInfo(Name, FamilyName, FatherName, BirthDate, GenderID, NationalId) values";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(s);
pst.setString(1,Name.getText());    // error is at this line!
pst.setString(2,FamilyName.getText());
pst.setString(3,FatherName.getText());
pst.setString(4,BirthDate.getText());
if (Male.isSelected()){
    GenderID=1;
} 
if (Female.isSelected()){
    GenderID=2;
}
pst.setInt(GenderID,5);
pst.setString(6,NationalId.getText());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

I get this error:

> The index 1 is out of range

But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The manner in which you asked the question seems to imply that you have no idea about such basic programming activities as debugging. You should look into that before asking on SO. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has no placeholders. Change it to this:

```
 String s = "insert into PersonalInfo (Name, FamilyName, FatherName, "
    + "BirthDate, GenderID, NationalId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

You also have a bug here:

```
pst.setInt(GenderID, 5);  // your code
pst.setInt(5, GenderID);  // correct code
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps definition of `s` should be

```
String s= "insert into PersonalInfo(Name, FamilyName, FatherName, BirthDate, GenderID, NationalId) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```